# Save and Load boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point in binary file

Tags: c++, boost

I need to save a variable of type `boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` 
into a file and then retrieve it from file.
time formatting is not important,I wish to save it as double.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get internal value with [time_point::time_since_epoch()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.time_point_hpp.time_point.time_since_epoch) member function for save.
And you can load time with [time_point(duration)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.time_point_hpp.time_point.time_point_c_2) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The steady clock defines it duration as `nanoseconds` ([here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.duration_hpp.duration_typedefs))

This in case uses at least 64 bits as its representation.

```
typedef duration<boost::int_least64_t, nano> nanoseconds;
```

So you could just serialize the representation of the duration. You'd have to cast it back to your clock's timepoint type at deserialization.

On a meta-level, when deserialized, the time-point won't "match" the current steady clock source (because it could be in a different process, after a reboot, even on a different machine). So you could contemplate

- defining your own special purpose clock (like: archive_clock)
- just storing the nanoseconds value, where the documentation describes its relevance and its (absent) relation to wall-clock time etc.